# 名前空間とクラスの配置について ( 一部分のクラスから参照されやすい名前空間の配置 )

Tags: 詳細設計

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上記画像について

- 青い枠線で囲まれたもの = 名前空間
- 赤い枠線で囲まれたもの = クラス

として

**Foo::FooFormクラスはFoo::Module::Mathクラスを使用し

Bar::BarFormクラスはBar::Module::Mathクラスを使用します。**

**Foo::Module::MathクラスはFoo名前空間にあるクラス以外からは使用されないようなメソッドが、

Bar::Module::MathクラスはBar名前空間にあるクラス以外からは使用されないようなメソッドが

書かれている**

とします。

また、
**Module::Mathクラスはあらゆるクラスから使用されるようなメソッドが**
書かれています。

このようなFoo名前空間とBar名前空間のような、
名前空間自体の配置を似通ったようなものにするのは
設計的に正しいでしょうか？

Comment: 名前空間はインポートしてしまえばどうとでもなりますが、`Math`が複数あるのは嫌われると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
例えば, Foo::Module::MathではなくFoo::Module::FooHelper、
Bar::Module::MathではなくFoo::Module::BarHelper…などだったらどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

開発規模にもよると思いますが、複数人で開発する際などは各担当箇所ごとにばらばらな構成になるよりは、多少冗長でもご質問のようにルール化して進めた方があとあと開発メンバの入れ替えなどが発生した場合混乱が少なくて済むことが多いです。

Comment: ルールを意識して設計するようにしてみます。
ありがとうございます！